# GameKit on OS X 10.7 work-around

Tags: objective-c, macos, game-center

I have a game with game center support on osx 10.8. On 10.7 it will fail to load because it cannot find the library. I know this feature comes with 10.8, but what can I do to don't use gamekit on 10.7 and use it on 10.8?

Comment: Two words: weak linkage.

Comment: the two words I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of examples of weak linkage, but the gist for using a class that may exist is:

```
Class C = NSClassFromString(@"SomeClassThatMayExistInRuntime");

if (C)
{
    id someObj = [C new];
    [someObj doSomethingWithThis];
    //or
    [someObj performSelector:@selector(doSomethingWithThis)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just weak link the framework. This allows the linker to decide what code to execute at runtime. Check the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-107837).